# PowerBuilder, function saveas generates empty files under Windows 10

Tags: pdf, windows-10, powerbuilder

I recently upgraded my computer to WINDOWS 10 and I am having troubles with the saveas function.

Using PowerBuilder 11.5 Build 2506 under WINDOWS 10. 
When I Use the function 'saveas' in order to generate a PDF file from a datawindow, it creates an empty file.

Does anyone have encountered this before ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please share some code. We are not a code writing service. Please refer to [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Have you tried to do any research? What have you tried? Questions here should have a clear problem/question, with research shown, and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Answer (score 0):

PowerBuilder does not have the native ability to generate PDFs prior to the most current version (2017 - which is now available from [Appeon](http://www.appeon.com)).  You must have been using some other tool (OCX, PDF printer type control, or Ghostscript) to do this.  Were these upgraded?  Also, PB 11.5 is not certified to run under Windows 10